# Optimizing Costs and Handling Longer Chats with OpenAI API in Laravel

Tags: php, optimization, laravel-8, openai-api

I'm currently working on a project where I need to implement a chat feature using the OpenAI API in Laravel. I'm utilizing the orhanerday/open-ai package, following the guidelines provided in the documentation here.

However, I've encountered an issue when dealing with longer chats. This approach consumes a significant amount of credits, resulting in higher costs for my client. Currently, when I send text to the API, it returns an ID for the message. I'm wondering if there's a way to utilize this ID to retrieve the context of the chat or implement some form of message filtering to reduce costs.

Any insights or suggestions on optimizing costs and handling longer chats with the OpenAI API in Laravel would be greatly appreciated.

In my Laravel application, I've implemented a function `callAi()` which uses the orhanerday/open-ai package to interact with the GPT API for generating responses in a chat interface. Below is the code snippet for this function:

```
use Orhanerday\OpenAi\OpenAi;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->open_ai_key = env('OPEN_IA_KEY');
    $this->open_ai = new OpenAi($this->open_ai_key);
}

public function callAi($prompt)
{
    try {
        $complete = $this->open_ai->chat([
            "model" => 'gpt-3.5-turbo-0125',
            'messages' => $prompt,
            'temperature' => 0.3,
            'max_tokens' => 50,
            'frequency_penalty' => 0,
            'presence_penalty' => 0.6
        ]);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Log::error(["Call AI error:" => $e]);
        return $e->getMessage();
    }

    return $complete;
}
```

The prompt parameter passed to `callAi()` is an array containing role-based messages, each with specific content. Here's an example format of the prompt array:

```json
[
    [
        "role" => "system",
        "content" => "You are a helpful assistant."
    ],
    [
        "role" => "user",
        "content" => "Who won the World Series in 2020?"
    ],
    [
        "role" => "assistant",
        "content" => "The Los Angeles Dodgers won the World Series in 2020."
    ],
    [
        "role" => "user",
        "content" => "Where was it played?"
    ],
]
```

However, when the conversation extends over multiple messages, it consumes a significant amount of credits, leading to higher costs. I'm seeking advice on how to optimize this process and potentially reduce costs while efficiently handling longer chats. Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.